# Using the Python/C API to get the values of PyStrings in the interpreter as CStrings within a C program

Tags: python, c, api, get

I've been messing around with the Python/C API and have this code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Initialize Python
    Py_Initialize();

    //Run file
    FILE *fp = fopen("Test.py", "r");

    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp,"Test.py");

    fclose(fp);

    //Run Python code
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(__NAME__)");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(__DESC__)");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(__SKIN__)");
    PyRun_SimpleString("onEnable()");

    //Finalize Python
    Py_Finalize();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Test.py contains this:

```
__NAME__ = "Frank"
__DESC__ = "I am a test script"
__SKIN__ = "random image"

def onEnable():
    print("In Func")
```

As you would expect, compiling and running the c program results in this:

Frank

I am a test script

random image

In Func

However, I need a way to get the python strings from interpreter, stick them in C strings and then print them, rather than using PyRun_SimpleString("print(blah)").

For example:

```
char *__NAME__;
__NAME__ = Py_GetObject("__NAME__")
```

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW: don't forget that variables starting with underscores are reserved and mustn't be used by user code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [PyString_AsString](http://docs.python.org/c-api/string.html#PyString_AsString). I think it goes something like this:

```
PyObject* module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject* o = PyObject_GetAttrString(module , "__NAME__");
if (PyString_Check(o))
{
    const char* name = PyString_AsString(o);
    // don't delete or modify "name"!
}
Py_DECREF(o);
```