# Pass string as a c_ubyte array to C

Tags: python, c, ctypes

In `C` I have a function that expects array of `unsigned char`s

```
void writedata(unsigned char *datapos, int datanum)
```

I would like to pass a standard string from Python instead

```
writedata = parallel.writedata
writedata.argtypes = [POINTER(c_ubyte), c_int]

a = "test string"
writedata(a, 11)
```

As far as I understand, string is actually an array of bytes/chars, and `a` is a pointer.  However, `ctypes` disagrees:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_c_ubyte instance instead of str
```

How can I get "real" pointer from a string?

**EDIT**: David Cullen provided a solution that takes string pointer as a parameter:

```
writedata.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_int]
```

That's fine, but I would like to supply both **byte array**s and **string**s to the function.  This means that this should also work

```
ll = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
uints = (c_ubyte*8)(*ll)
writedata(uints, 8)
```

I am curious why I can't do both, because in terms of memory I *think* byte arrays and strings should be the same?  Perhaps this is all about pointer conversions?

I also tried make two `ctypes` connections to the same `C` function, and this does not work.

**SOLUTION**: I have reformulated the question and received the best answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64838842/2957687

Comment: I think you may find usefull this question : [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086318/using-the-python-c-api-to-get-the-values-of-pystrings-in-the-interpreter-as-cstr)

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper It must be `ctypes`.  I already written a huge program and all other `Python` <-> `C` communication is done by `ctypes`

Comment: "As far as I understand, string is actually an array of bytes/chars" - a *C* string is, but not a Python string. A Python string is an abstract sequence of Unicode code points, which may have multiple different in-memory representations.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Fair argument.  What about if I know there are only ASCII characters, or if I put `b` in front, i.e. `b"test string"`?

Comment: @Pygmalion: Putting a `b` in front makes it `bytes`, not `str`, so it should work.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Well the `ctypes` returns the same error.  Even with `b`, it is still `str`.

Comment: @Pygmalion Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: @DavidCullen Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the same function if we convert strings to match the required argument types:

```py
def writedata(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(value)) (*bytearray(value))
    writedataf(value, len(value))
```

To test my theory, I created a very simple library:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void writedata(unsigned char *datapos, int datanum) {
    for (int index = 0; index < datanum; index++) {
        putchar(datapos[index]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

I created a shared library for macos using

```
clang -Wall -Werror -shared -fpic main.c -o libwritedata.so
```

I coped the shared library to `/usr/local/lib` and created this Python script:

```py
import ctypes

writedataf = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/local/lib/libwritedata.so').writedata
writedataf.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte), ctypes.c_int]

def writedata(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(value)) (*bytearray(value))
    writedataf(value, len(value))

x = "a short string"
writedata(x)
uints = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(x)) (*bytearray(x))
writedata(uints)
```

**Output**

```
a short string
a short string
```

Comment: +1 Uh, oh, it works, but I am sometimes accessing the same function with actual char/byte arrays, i.e. `uints = (c_ubyte*8)(*name_of_list)`, `writedata(uints, 8)`.  Can I have both?

Comment: @Pygmalion I modifed the script to handle both data types.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but this will not work for me, because I `malloc` different `struct`s in the C library that have to be available for all functions...  If I load several instances of the same C library this `struct`s won't be visible.

Comment: @Pygmalion I modified the script so that the library is only loaded once.